# Custom output html menu in magento

Tags: magento

basicly magento generate menu html:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top">
      <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="level0 nav-1 first level-top parent">
      <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Category</span></a>
      <ul class="level0">
         <li class="level1 nav-2-1 first">
            <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Sub Category</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="level1 nav-2-1">
            <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Sub Category</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="level1 nav-2-1 last">
            <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>Sub Category</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

now, i want custom change output html menu (add more class html, add more element html...) somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's different tutorials for doing this, but here's what I did:

Save /app/code/frontend/design/default/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml to /app/code/frontend/design/yourpackagename/yourthemename/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml and edit as follows:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li  class="level0 nav-1 first level-top"><a href="/"  class="level-top" ><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

To get yourpackagename and yourthemename, use System - Configuration - Design
hth, sconnie

Comment: yes, i did, but i want to have the sub menu, I'll add one tag <span class="arrow_sub"> </ span> on, how do I do?